# Show readonly feild in edit form using client object model c#

Tags: list, list-view, custom-form, form, list-form

How can I show Read Only fields in edit form through Client Object Model c#, I'm giving `showineditform=true` but it is not working

```
Title.Required = true; 
Title.ReadOnlyField = true; 
Title.SetShowInDisplayForm(true); 
Title.SetShowInEditForm(true); 
Title.SetShowInNewForm(true);
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: Any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the edit form and configure the atribute "ControlMode" to the value "Display", see:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
```

Comment: I need through c#, client object model console app